# Debug Exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio I select Debug->Exceptions then add an exception that will be ignored by visual studio.

Where is this information stored?

When I switch solutions I seem to lose this setting.  Is there anyway to set this for everyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is being stored in the user options file for the solution (.suo)